# Javafx load child Controller

Tags: java, javafx, controller, javafx-8, fxml

I am working with linking controllers and `.fxml`s but I have a problem, I have in my `Main.fxml` file the

```
<fx:include source="FistChild.fxml">
<fx:include source="SecondChild.fxml">
```

Every child fxml has a controller class, and the main fxml also has a Controller. In my main controller I want a reference to my child controllers, but if I try to get it by loading their .fxml files and get the controller from there, then the child controller is initialized two times, once at the `<fx:include>` and once at `loader.load()`. So how can I get the reference for the child controllers without loading them again? I see there is a tag `<fx:reference>` I tried to use this but I don't even know what is that for, and how to use it, and I don't even know that tag is the solution for this. Do you have any idea what did I wrong?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers

Comment: Thank you both, I have also found the link that @James_D and I have tried exactly this way to give them an id, but the problem was with the naming. I give as fx:id="firstChildController" then I got a reference to my content of the `.fxml` in my case of a `TableView` not of the Controller, but now it is working fine. So  @fabian you can post the answer to get the points for it.